# HTTPS Response shows non expected values

Tags: java, https, httpresponse, http-toolkit

Good Evening,

i run into a strange problem which i never encountered before so i hope someone might help me.

I am sending a request to a server and expect a certain response.

Doing the call via

```
response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

Parallel i am checking the request via HTTP Toolkit.
There i can see the server responds with 200 OK and a certain byteStream which i expect (
starts with

```
0a a1 0a 0a 1e 74 79 70 65 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 61 70 69 73 2e
```

In the code i am using
System.out.println("ResponseBody: " + (response.body().byteString().hex()));
to valide that is shows the same result as in HTTP Toolkit but for whatever reason i am getting a totally different response. Starts with

```
1f8b0800000000000403a594cb4a033114866d4bbd
```

Why there is a difference. I also tried to stop intercepting the request via Http Toolkit to make sure it's not manipulated by the tool but that results also in the nonexpected value.
Also tried to debug it but as soon as i can see the response.body in the IDE it already has the unexpected result in it.

I hope someone run into the same problem and knows a solution.

Cheers

Comment: 1f8b is the magic number for `gzip`. What is the server returned in the Content-Encoding response header ?

Comment: You are correct. content-encoding:
gzip

I missed that and focussed only on the content-type

Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok i tested it and decompressed the gzip. Now i am getting the expected results.